# Selenium Firefox Webdriver in Java (run parameters)

Tags: java, firefox, unix, selenium, xvfb

I've developed a testing unit with Selenium 2 in Java that uses Firefox engine.

The deploy machine has no display so I'm using Xvfb to create it. Unfortunatly that forces me to start java using `DISPLAY=:0 java -jar xxx.jar`.
I've searched selenium javadoc and searched some sources but can't find the method that java uses to launch Firefox, witch is my goal, making java launch firefox using same method `DISPLAY=:0 firefox ...`.

Long story short:
I must do `DISPLAY=:0 java -jar xxx.jar` but I want java to do `DISPLAY=:XX firefox ...` instead of `firefox ...` so I can also use multiple displays.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but out of curiosity: How does it behave when you launch it "normally"? I guess you considered [HtmlUnitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver), right?

Comment: I want "real" browser so HtmlUnitDriver fails (js). It behaves as a normal display, I can even take screenshots and see how it looks. So its basically a normal display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're actually using Xvfb and Selenium in production with a dozen Firefox instances that work continuously. 
We use `xvfb-run java -jar xxx.jar` which select a free display to run all the firefox instances for this program. If screenshot is your concern, you can use only one display and still have a dozen Firefox taking screenshots for different websites at the same time

We wrapped this under a shell script, and that's transparent.

If you really want each selenium server to have its very display, you can overwrite it in the browser string specified in configuration. just make a shell script that do `xvfb-run /usr/bin/firefox` and pass this script to your config. That should do the trick

Have a good testing

Answer (score 2):

We have made an bash file which sets the display and then starts firefox.
We have put it into the path under the name `firefox`, so selenium finds it using `which`
to locate the firefox binary.

Answer (score 2):

Write a 'proxy' program that does a shell execute with the desired parameters; then point "webdriver.firefox.bin" property at your proxy program.  I don't think this can be a java program because it is executed through the java command.  It would probably have to be native code, probably C and something like "system ("DISPLAY=:XX firefox ...");"

Comment: almost like correct answer but using shell script is better. Thanks for ideia though.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this manual, I used this a while ago to do about the same:

http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/

TLDR;

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ firefox
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Dispite of your answer solves my original problem I want to choose, at java, which display to use.

Comment: @Ciro Sooo, [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) dynamically calling the commands needed is not an option? (no, I still don't understand most things neither in the question nor in the answer)

Comment: Dont think so, It's selenium library that runs and manage open browser.

Comment: Right. Anyway, the commands that call Firefox from Selenium are: [`FirefoxBinary, lines 77-80`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.java) which is then finally executed in [`UnixProcess, executeAsync(), line 93+`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/os/UnixProcess.java)